# Zentools compatible version

Tags: extensions, joomla-4.x

I want to use zentools. Currently im working with joomla 4.1.0 .
So, I was wondering, Is there a version of zentools that is compatible with joomla 4.1.0 ??

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour] while ypu wait for support/feedback.  If you would like to improve the English in your question or add details such as research that you have already done on this topic, you may [edit] your question at any time and as many times as you need.

Answer (score 3):

The Joomla Extension Directory has "Zentools" in its listing: https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/zentools/

The most recent version of Zentools (v1.14.6) is only listed as compatible with Joomla 3. It was released 3.5 years ago (Aug 2018), so it's not compatible with Joomla 4.1.0.

Maybe you could contact its developer JoomlaBamboo to ask when they will release a Joomla 4.1.0 compatible version?

Answer (score 0):

Zentools and Zentools 2 are different extensions. I did ask the current owner of the Joomlabamboo (JoomlArt) if they would update the Zentools2 extension to Joomla 4. They said no.

The closest replacement that I am aware of is [Widgetkit by Yootheme](https://yootheme.com/widgetkit-joomla-gallery). I have not yet tried it, but it allows most of the flexibility that Zentool2 has. It is being maintained and is compatible with Joomla 4 and 5.

If you were looking for something specific to create and have some HTML coding skills, you could use the pro version of [ArticlesAnywhere from Regular Labs](https://regularlabs.com/articlesanywhere) and the framework that your template uses (Bootstrap is the most common but your template docs should tell you). You would use ArticlesAnywhere to fetch the data; use the framework's docs to create the visual effects. This is a bit more effort, but it could be closer to what you want.